The effect of input and output impedance
This picture shows the classical feedback system and this assumption about this system.
"the input impedances of both the amplifier and the feedback network are
infinite and their output impedances are zero."

My questions are:

If there is a numeric impedance for the amplifier and feedback network, how can I show this impedance? How can I draw the circuit diagram? I know, I draw a resistor symbol, but how can I connect it to the other part of circuit? I can't visualise it. How can I draw input and output impedance?

What is the effect of infinite and zero input impedance?

What is the effect of infinite and zero output impedance?



It is assumed that at least one of the two quadrupoles presented by the applicant is active. The configuration is the well-known Series-Shunt and the study must be done using the H parameters and the equivalent quadrupoles thereof. We then proceed with a simplification of the circuit obtained, depending on the requirements, as in the figure:

